# how to get the file from a folder using php?

Tags: php

i have one folder,in that i have many files and i have four buttons also,the buttons are first,next,previous,last. when i click on first button i want to get first file content and it should display which file currently working on.when i click on next button i want to get next file content,when i click on previous button want to get the previous file content,when i click on last button i want to get the last file content.

```
$next_slide=$text+"1";
echo $next_slide;
$a_str = array($_POST["content"]);
$contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $a_str);
$contents .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;   
$get_content=file_get_contents($foldername.'/'.$next_slide."-html",$contents);
```

when i click on first getting first file content,passing the 1 as to php fie and adding +1 for get the next file content,but not get the second file content
please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following and -html is not a valid extension

```
$handler = fopen($foldername.'/'.$next_slide.'.html','r');
$get_content = fread($handler);
```

Comment: thanks,but it's not work for me,because i have file like abc.html,def.html,ert.html,xxxx.html etc.so when i click next it's should get the content from def.html file                            please tell me how to get?

Comment: sorry,it's not working,next_slide value as 2 so how can i get the def.html file $foldername/2.html iam getting.instead of 2 i want to get the 2nd file content

Answer (score 0):

You have to save customer choice:

```
 $choice = 0;
 if(isset($_SESSION['actual'])){
     $choice = $_SESSION['actual']; or COOKIE as you want.
 }
 if($_GET['next']){
      $choice++;
 }
 elseif($_GET['previous']){
      $choice--;
 }
 elseif($_GET['first']){
      $choice = 'first';
 }
 elseif($_GET['last']){
      $choice = 'last';
 }
 $_SESSION['actual'] = $choice;

 $get_content=file_get_contents($foldername.'/'. $choice ."-html",$contents);
```